# Redirecting from login

Tags: hooks

I want my site to redirect after login to site_url('/') for all users except 'administrator'
I also want the admin_bar showing for certain roles ie event_planner. It is all working except that when and event_planner logs on and then clicks on the admin bar to go into admin it redirects to '/'.
The hook being used to redirect is 'admin_init' which is clearly wrong.
Is there another hook I could use to initially redirect to / on login but not when pressing the dashboard on the admin bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a filter called [`login_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/).

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse377295_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
function wpse377295_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ) {
    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        // It's possible that the $user param is a WP_Error. If so, bail out.
        return $url;
    }
    if ( ! user_can( $user, 'update_core' ) {
        // Only admin users can update core, normally.
        $url = site_url( '/' );
    }
    return $url;
}
```

There's a more complete example in the filter documentation's [User Contributed Notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/#user-contributed-notes).

### References

- [`login_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/)
- [`user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/user_can/)

Comment: Brilliant, worked exactly how I wanted. I have upranked you but it has not shown due to me being fairly new.